# undefined method `gsub' for 2014-10-31 17:55:55 +0530:Time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

While executing the following i got an error message 'undefined method `gsub' for 2014-10-31 17:55:55 +0530:Time'

the code is

$(document).ready(function(){ 
           jQuery(".countdown_timer_widget").countdowntimer("<%= j (Time.now) %>", "<%= j (@end_time) %>");
         });

I don't know how to correct it , help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ jQuery(".countdown_timer_widget").countdowntimer("<%= j (Time.now.to_s) %>", "<%= j (@end_time) %>");
});
```

The method gsub is for strings therefore you have to convert the Date to a string.

Comment: @prakashS Np glad it worked out for you - I was the first who responded but you are accepting the other answer. Also I wrote a why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ jQuery(".countdown_timer_widget").countdowntimer("<%= j (Time.now.to_s) %>", "<%= j (@end_time.to_s) %>");
});
```

Comment: @prakashS what you can do your best is accept an answer and upvote the other one